# Configure IIS to Serve Django Applications

Tags: django, iis, wsgi, fastcgi

I'm trying to publish a Django web application (created with `Python 2.7.15`) via IIS. First of all I installed the application:

```bat
:: setup folders
mkdir C:\Software\MyApp\
cd C:\Software\MyApp\

:: clone the git Repository
git clone https://gitlab.com/blablabla.git C:\Software\MyApp\MyAppServer

:: create the virtualenv
python -m pip install --upgrade pip
pip install virtualenv
virtualenv py2_env
call py2_env\Scripts\activate.bat

:: install the python-requirements in the virtualenv
pip install -r C:\Software\MyApp\MyAppServer\requirements.txt

:: copy all static files in C:\var\www
python C:\Software\MyApp\MyAppServer\manage.py collectstatic

:: just to check if the app works (and it works!)
python C:\Software\MyApp\MyAppServer\manage.py runserver
```

At this point, my folders organization is:

```bat
C:\
└── Software\
    └── MyApp\
        ├── py2_env\
        │   ├── Include\
        │   ├── Lib\
        │   ├── Scripts\
        │   └── tcl\
        └── MyAppServer\
            ├── manage.py
            ├── ...
            └── myapp_django_server\
                ├── urls.py
                ├── wsgi.py
                └── ...
```

And the packages installed in my `py2_env` virtual env are:

```bat
(py2_env) C:\Software\MyApp\py2_env\Scripts>pip freeze --local
Django==1.11.2
djangorestframework==3.6.3
numpy==1.12.1
pytz==2018.7
wfastcgi==3.0.0
```

At this point I configure IIS following [this](http://blog.mattwoodward.com/2016/07/running-django-application-on-windows.html) guide (I jumped to the **Configure IIS to Serve Django Applications** chapter) but, at the end, if I browse to http://localhost:81 I get this error:

```bat
Error occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Software\EVARplanning\py2_env\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py", line 847, in main
    result = handler(record.params, response.start)
TypeError: get_wsgi_application() takes no arguments (2 given)


StdOut: 

StdErr:
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Looks like you missed off the closing parenthesis after `get_wsgi_application(` in your WSGI_HANDLER setting.

Comment: Thanks! I delete the single parenthesis in my WSGI_HANDLER (inside the IIS FastCGI Settings). But now I have a different error (I updated the question right now)

Comment: No you need both the opening and closing parentheses. (Sorry, I edited my original comment.)

Comment: Thanks, it works perfectly now!

Comment: BTW, at this moment, it is not a good idea to host Python apps on IIS, https://blog.lextudio.com/shifting-to-azure-app-service-on-linux-b216f4584b03

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my `WSGI_HANDLER` in the IIS's `FastCGI Settings`. I converted it's value from `django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application` to `django.core.wsgi.get_wsgi_application()` and then it works.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is this `web.config` file right next to `manage.py`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="Django" path="*" verb="*" modules="FastCgiModule" scriptProcessor="D:\web\my-api\Scripts\python.exe|D:\web\my-api\Lib\site-packages\wfastcgi.py" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Also make sure the  `ApplicationPool` for your site in IIS is using `LocalSystem` and not `ApplicationPoolIdentity`.

The rest should be easy to setup.